# How to save or update the excel file in Gitlab repository during the pipeline execution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm executing my test scripts in gitlab pipeline. In one of scenario I will be reading the data from excel (I use apache POI to achieve it) and use it in test case. Then I'm trying to update the same excel sheet with custom value during run time and trying save the excel file (excel file is saved in gitlab repository). I cannot save the excel sheet during execution from git.

Same code works from local system.

Can anybody help me how to save the file in gitlab repo while execution in pipeline

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there is no error, it needs to save the changes but it is not doing so

Comment: Are you getting the correct path on the gitlab ci and also do you correct permissions to edit the file ?

Comment: Actually path looks like /builds/XXXXXXXX/projectNmae/src/test/resources/ Excel/XXXXX.xlsx